# Thread during read() operation

Tags: multithreading, file-io

When read() from disk operation (blocking operation) is called in a thread. What happens in Thread?

1.) Is CPU idle unit data is transferred to memory? or Wait() and scheduler switches to another Thread?
2.) If Thread is in Wait state, how does it wake up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty open-ended question that can't be answered concisely. What happens is very dependent on the operating system that you are using. You say Linux, but even then, depending on the version, configuration, and a whole range of other things, it's impossible to say what may (or may not) happen.

Linux is a pre-emptive multi-tasking kernel. There are lots of articles, blogs, and other resources that cover how such kernels work. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking.

To address your questions directly:

1.) Depending on the hardware and driver, yes, it's possible that data could be transferred into memory while the CPU is idle. If there are other processes to run, the kernel may run them while waiting for the data to be read.

2.) A hardware interrupt generated by the disk controller could wake up an idle CPU and let the kernel return the data to the user-land process that called read().

If you are curious about exactly what happens, I could encourage you to dig into the kernel code. It's available for everyone to see, so why not, right? ;)